# Testing for an object key in an array of objects using mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

If I have an object that is an array of objects

```
{ "places": [ {city: "Pittsburgh", state: "PA"} ] }
```

how do I test to see if the array at index 0 (places[0]) has an object with a key "city"?  I tried this but it didn't work

```
expect( {"places": [ {"city": "Pittsburgh", "state": "PA"} ] } ).to.nested.include({"places[0]" : "city"});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `to.have.nested.property` instead of `to.nested.include`:

```
var obj = {"places": [ {"city": "Pittsburgh", "state": "PA"} ] };

expect(obj).to.have.nested.property("places[0].city");
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!